# Finding a email chain in Outlook 2010?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook-2010

How can I look at a email thread, with many people responding to the emails, my replies and forwards etc. Can I achieve this in Microsoft Outlook 2010?

Answer (score 1):

Actually this can be done by selecting the view to be "Show as Conversations".
This link helped:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/find-all-messages-in-the-same-thread-HA010251803.aspx